# Pass a parameter has its onload

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

...

and I want to send a parameter from my action

Comment: Learn more about the wall between Java/JSP and JavaScript here: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML syntax is wrong. It should be

```
<body onload="..."> ...
```

If you are actually passing a string parameter don't forget to quote and escape it:

```
<body onload="someJSFunction('<%= StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(someObject.getSomeAttribute()) >')")>
```

Answer (score 0):

just put your parameter in there like this:

```
<%= yourParameter %>
```

(assuming the parameter is a String or has a usable toString() method)